# Is any independent counting process Poisson?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I have seen a proof for the following statement: If a counting process $\left\{ N(t) \mid t\ge 0\right\}$ is homogeneous and has independent increments, i.e., $N(b_1)-N(a_1)$, $\dots$, $N(b_n)-N(a_n)$ are independent whenever $(a_1, b_1]$, $\dots$, $(a_n, b_n] \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ are disjoint, then it is a Poisson process.

But I wonder if the statement remains true also when the process is inhomogeneous. I.e., is any counting process with independent increments a Poisson process?

Comment: No, e.g., the deterministic process $N_t = \lfloor t\rfloor$: the increments are deterministic, and so independent, and the only Poisson random variable with zero variance is identically $0$, but the counts over intervals of length $>1$ are clearly nonzero with zero variance.